# Pihole in Oracle cloud free stops dns resolution

Tags: 20.04, dns, oracle

i am using oracle cloud to run pihole.
`/etc/resolv.conf` is

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search vcn01151XXX.oraclevcn.com
```

I am running ubuntu 20.04 minimal version

When i install pihole it stops all internet pings and DNS resolution.
How do i install pihole. Some sort of service is using port 53 because i tried docker and it says its in use.The issue is if it messes up i have to delete and rebuild image.

Any help. Tried lot of solutions to find how `resolv.conf` is populated but it doesn't say which service is rewriting the file after reboot.How can i run pihole on it and make dns work?

Comment: /etc/esolv.conf is getting written  from  /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf . I cannot edit both these files or delete it. I dont have internet to install any other packages, I think some process is locking it .

Comment: any  one knows how to install pihole on oracle cloud or google cloud?